# Scala: Extract types from generic parameters

Tags: scala, types, type-inference, inference

I have a class like this:

```
abstract class Foo[I, T, A <: Bar[I, T]](x: SomeClass[A]){
```

When I want to inherit class Foo, I've to specify types T and I, which could be extracted from type parameters of type A. (I.e. there are enough data to extract these types.) Does the Scala compiler allow to extract them somehow? I'd like to write something like:

```
abstract class Foo[A <: Bar[_, _]](x: SomeClass[A]){
    type Bar[I, T] = A    // <-- something like pattern matching
```

It is strange that I can write that, but the `type Bar[I, T] = A` line does not seem to declare anything. The line passes, but I can use neither type `I` nor type `T`.

Can I do something similar?

I know I could use `abstract class Foo[I, T](x: SomeClass[A]){` and then define `type A = Bar[I, T]`, but it loses some universality. Additionaly, this case means more (boilerplate) code for the code users, because they are likely to define a shortcut (i.e. type alias) for `Bar[I, T]`.

I can rewrite the abstract class `Foo` to a trait and I probably will do so. But I am not sure if it could help.

Answer (score 1):

When type parameters are going to be unhandy one should give abstract types a try:

```
scala> class Bar[I, T](i: I, t: T)
defined class Bar

scala> class SomeClass[A](a: A)
defined class SomeClass

scala> trait Trait { type I; type T; type A = Bar[I,T] }
defined trait Trait

scala> class Foo(x: SomeClass[Foo#A]) extends Trait { type I = String; type T = String }
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(new SomeClass(new Bar("", ""))) // works
res0: Foo = Foo@7e1f613c

scala> new Foo(new SomeClass(new Bar("", 0))) // does not work
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: String
              new Foo(new SomeClass(new Bar("", 0)))
                                                ^
```

Comment: I am not sure it meets my needs. Sure I can construct type A = `Bar[I, T]` from types `I` and `T`. But I want a reverse process - reconstruct types `I` and `T` from a given type `A <: Bar[_, _]`. The main reason why I'd like to do so is that the user is likely to have a typedef for `Bar[_, _]`, so this way would reduce the boilerplate.